# What spell do wizards use to bind elves?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter books there are several house elves. (I'm looking for a canon answer)
How do wizards bind them so powerfully?
What spell do they use to accomplish this?
And does anyone know if this spell is considered evil or Dark Magic?
(I can split this question up if necessary)

Comment: Do you mean bind them into servitude?  Because I'm pretty sure that's just a matter of cultural conditioning.

Comment: Well, if you can prove it by canon... I'll try to give it a shot.

Comment: @AdeleC: Yes, how do they bind them into servitude...

Comment: @djm There isn't a spell for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Professor Dumbledore indicated to Harry that House Elves were the way they are because of wizards. Nowhere are we told how this was done in the books. I has been left to our imagination.